# Create SQL Server Authentication in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've tried connecting to MSSQL(installed) from Visual Studio using the login created upon installing MSSQL.

Now, I have a new computer and I installed Visual Studio 2015 in it. Is it possible for me to create SQL Server Login without installing MSSQL then connect to it via VS2015?

Comment: If you have sql server installed anywhere on a network that is accessible then you could login in to that instance from vs. Somehow, I doubt this is what you are asking though.

Comment: Yea but I sold my old one. I'm just wondering if its possible to create an sql instance without installing MSSQL

Comment: If you could get away using a large subset of SQL Server functionality then try the community edition of SQL Express, its free.

Comment: Do you think LocalDb would suffice for development? I only need to store the data then query, and look at the data. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds reasonable for your needs. I have not used sql express in Visual Studio, however, I would think you could add a database connection the same way as you would a standard sql instance.

Comment: If you'll use it only for this purpose, store some data then query, I think you can use that way. But before all, check the documentation to see if some funtionality you would need is on the express version :)